# Connected subgraph from several strongly connected components

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose, given a connected directed graph G, with several strongly connected components in it: G1, G2, ... All of them are known and there is a function f : Gi -> bool that returns true for some of them and false from others.

Now lets take all Gi, such that f(Gi) is true and ignore others. Is there some easy approach to build connected subgraph in G, containing all of them, and minimal number of other edges from G?

Comment: What is your current approach and what difficulties you were spotted?

Comment: This is probably equivalent to the NP-hard Steiner tree problem on unweighted graphs.

Comment: Yep, I supposed it is computably hard. Now I am using some domain-specific heuristic, that is really awful, and I want to find acceptable solution for the problem in full generality. Thanks for Steiner tree, now I am reading about approximation algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Make condensation and then make spanning tree in subgraph `f(Gi) = true` of this condensation. Hint, condensation is always partially ordered which makes spanning tree construction easier.

Comment: This is a 2-approximation.

Comment: Great observation (upvoted this one) but it seems to be far from minimal resulting graph. The reason is: I need also "false" condensations, and this complicates things. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: In this case, I do not understand your task. It is not clear what you would like to achieve. What is the point of `f` when you want also `f(Gi) = false`? What edges you would like to minimise? Which edges you would like to remove? Would you like to remove edges in strong components or just edges between components? Can you give example?

Comment: No, I want just f(GI) = true. I meant, that if I do not make condensation of f(Gi) = false connected components, I can not easily build spanning tree. Now after tree is built, I might need to somehow uncondence false ones and build real paths inside them, or so.